# Calling function plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql

but I cant manage to call it.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION wyplaty_dla_prac_o_email (threshold_value integer,email_of text)
RETURNS TABLE(f1 int,f2 timestamp)
AS
$$
begin
select amount, payment_date from payment p join customer c on p.customer_id=c.customer_id 
where amount > $1 and email =$2;



end;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and when I call it

```
select * from wyplaty_dla_prac_o_email(6,'dana.hart@sakilacustomer.org')
```

it says that ERROR: It was not indicated where the query results should be saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a return statement. Your function is executing a query but not doing anything with the result, which is producing the error.

You need to return the results of your query like so:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION wyplaty_dla_prac_o_email (threshold_value integer,email_of text)
RETURNS TABLE(f1 int,f2 timestamp)
AS  $$ begin
return query 
  select amount, payment_date from payment p join 
  customer c on p.customer_id=c.customer_id 
  where amount > $1 and email =$2;
end; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Alternatively you could just specify the function in SQL instead of using plpgsql if it's just a wrapper around a query and save yourself the overhead.

Comment: Alternatively use `language sql` and then the `return query` is no longer necessary

Comment: I did say that in the last paragraph as well. But yes, that's correct.